# Symfony 2 + Doctrine 2 - DateTime fields not persisting

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I have an entity of type `Blah` with the following fields:

```
/**
 * @var datetime $begin
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="begin", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $begin;

/**
 * @var datetime $end
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="end", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $end;
```

With the following getters/setters:

```
/**
 * @param $begin
 */
public function setBegin($begin)
{
    $this->begin = $begin;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getBegin()
{
    return $this->begin;
}

/**
 * @param $end
 */
public function setEnd($end)
{
    if ($end < $this->begin) {
        $this->end = $this->begin->add(\DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'));
    } else {
        $this->end = $end;
    }
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getEnd()
{
    return $this->end;
}
```

And a corresponding form type that has:

```
    $builder->add('begin', 'datetime', array(
            'label' => 'Begin',
            'required' => false,
    ));

    $builder->add('end', 'datetime', array(
            'label' => 'End',
            'required' => false,
    ));
```

And the form handling portion of the method in question:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new BlahType(), $blah);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $postData = $request->request->all();

        if (!empty($postData['save'])) {
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            $numThings = $postData['blah']['numThings'];

            if ($numThings) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < $numThings; ++$i) {
                    $thing = new Thing();

                    $blah->addThing($thing);
                }
            }

            $em->persist($blah);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
```

When I attempt to save these entries, `null` gets passed back to the entity despite the fact that the populated entity contains two arrays for each entry

Screen shot of what's passed back to the entity:

[image]

Screen shot of what the populated entity supposedly has after `$form->handleRequest()`:

[image]

Needless to say, I'm confused.  According to the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html), a `datetime` field should default to having an `input` of, well, `datetime`, yet I'm getting the data back as a series of two arrays per field - one array with the day, month, and year, and the other with the hour and minutes.  And even with that, `null` is what's being passed back to the entity and persisted in the db.

It's baffling.  Any suggestions/answers?

EDIT: The form itself has `null`s in its `viewData`:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Problem was due to PHP inexplicably only recognizing Continent/City timezones instead of the old Country/Timezone timezones.  US/Eastern is no longer valid.